# Property doesn't update when set in the Business Logic

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, inotifypropertychanged

I need to set a property in the Business Logic with a method in the Business Logic. If you run my code you can see the first String "Target Location" changes successfully, but the second one "Some Other String" doesn't change its value in the view. "PropertyChanged" in the BusinessLogic.cs is null. I have absolutely no idea WHY it's null! Can someone explain me this behaviour and how I can fix this?

I have the following files in my project:

**MainWindow.xaml**

```
<Window x:Class="TestWpf.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TestWpf"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<StackPanel>
    <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=TargetLocation}"></TextBox>
    <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=SomeOtherString}"></TextBox>
    <Button Click="ChangeTextButton_Click">Change Target Location</Button>
    <Button Click="ChangeSomeOtherStringButton_Click">Change some other string</Button>
</StackPanel>
```

**MainWindow.xaml.cs**

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    MainViewModel mainViewModel = new MainViewModel();
    mainViewModel.TargetLocation = @"A:\Old_Location";
    mainViewModel.SomeOtherString = "Old String...";

    DataContext = mainViewModel;
}

private void ChangeTextButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    MainViewModel mainViewModel = (MainViewModel)DataContext;
    mainViewModel.TargetLocation = @"B:\New_Location";
}

private void ChangeSomeOtherStringButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    MainViewModel mainViewModel = (MainViewModel)DataContext;
    mainViewModel.ChangeSomeOtherString();
}
```

**MainViewModel.cs**

```
public class MainViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string targetLocation;

    public string TargetLocation
    {
        get
        {
            return targetLocation;
        }
        set
        {
            targetLocation = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("TargetLocation");
        }
    }

    public string SomeOtherString
    {
        get
        {
            return BusinessLogicClass.GetInstance().SomeOtherString;
        }
        set
        {
            BusinessLogicClass.GetInstance().SomeOtherString = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("SomeOtherString");
        }
    }

    public void ChangeSomeOtherString()
    {
        BusinessLogicClass.GetInstance().ChangeSomeOtherString();
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

**BusinessLogicClass**

```
public class BusinessLogicClass : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private static BusinessLogicClass instance;

    public static BusinessLogicClass GetInstance()
    {
        if (instance == null)
        {
            instance = new BusinessLogicClass();
        }

        return instance;
    }

    private BusinessLogicClass()
    {

    }

    private string someOtherString;

    public string SomeOtherString
    {
        get
        {
            return someOtherString;
        }
        set
        {
            someOtherString = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("SomeOtherString");
        }
    }

    public void ChangeSomeOtherString()
    {
        SomeOtherString = "New String!";
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> "PropertyChanged" in the BusinessLogic.cs is null. I have absolutely no idea WHY it's null!

`PropertyChanged` in the BusinessLogic class is null because there are no bindings that use properties in this class as their source.  The source properties for both of your bindings are on your `MainViewModel` class.

WPF doesn't scan through all classes that happen to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`.  And even if it did, how would it know that a `PropertyChanged` event fired from your `BusinessLogic` class means that it needs to update the TextBox bound to the `SomeOtherString` property on your `MainViewModel`?  WPF can't read your code to find this out.

The simplest fix is to fire a `PropertyChanged` event inside your `ChangeSomeOtherString()` method:

```
    public void ChangeSomeOtherString()
    {
        BusinessLogicClass.GetInstance().ChangeSomeOtherString();
        OnPropertyChanged("SomeOtherString");    // Add this line
    }
```

This way WPF knows that the value of the `SomeOtherString` property has changed and will perform the necessary update to the TextBox.

Comment: Thank you very much for the explanation! The fix works for me :)